# How to write TDD code for user profile update in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to create a TDD first before using my function in the app.

I have already created the update function, update works but before that i want a test case running. So i have created this test case.

```
/** @test */
public function updateUser()
{

    $this->withExceptionHandling(); 

    //creating a user
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    //passing updating values
    $response = $this->put('users/update_profile', [
        'name' => 'name123',
        'phoneno' => 9842345562,
        'address' => 'newwwww'
    ]);

    $this->assertEquals('name123', User::first()->name);
    $this->assertEquals(9842345562, User::first()->phoneno);
    $this->assertEquals('newwwww', User::first()->address);

}

//update function
public function update(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'phoneno' => $request->phoneno,
        'address' => $request->address
    ]);

    session()->flash('success', 'User Proifile Updated');

    return redirect(route('users.view-profile'));
}
```

Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'name123'
+'Tad Predovic'

Only getting this error.

Comment: you want to test the authenticated user can update his profile data?

Comment: Does this require the user to login first? Does the response redirect the user to the login page? You may need this line after creating a user: $this->actingAs($user);

Comment: Yes i want to check who is authenticated and if he or she is then the authenticated user can update his data. I dont know who to create an auth user in the test

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on `User::first()` as your first record may not the one you just created. Instead refresh the model you already have to get the updated values from the DB after your new values are set. You can use `$user-refresh()` before your assertions

```
/** @test */
public function updateUser() {

    $this->withExceptionHandling(); 

    //creating a user
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    //signing in as the new user
    $this->actingAs($user);

    //passing updating values
    $response = $this->put('users/update_profile', [
        'name' => 'name123',
        'phoneno' => 9842345562,
        'address' => 'newwwww'
    ]);

    //Get new values
    $user->refresh();

    $this->assertEquals('name123', $user->name);
    $this->assertEquals(9842345562, $user->phoneno);
    $this->assertEquals('newwwww', $user->address);
}
```

Comment: @KaranShrestha I would still recommend this approach, or using `assertDatabaseHas` instead. I also noticed that you are trying to update the logged user, but your test doesn’t show that the user is logged in. You may want to try using `$this->actingAs($user)` after you create your user.

Comment: I totally agree with @dr-ermio, you are coupling your test code with you model. assertDatabaseHas assertion is the best option.  You can find more information at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing